# What do the buttons on the Android power control do?

Tags: app-widgets

The first two buttons on the Android power control widget are Wifi and Bluetooth. What do the other 3 buttons do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last three are GPS Receiver, Data Sync and Screen Brightness. As seen [here](http://www.randomtools.net/android-1-6-version-update-donut-adds-new-power-control-widget-69.html).

And it looks like the Extended Controls app gives you even more control ([android police article](http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/07/29/app-of-the-week-extendedcontrols-a-power-control-widget-on-steroids/)) and here it is [on appbrain](http://www.appbrain.com/app/extended-controls/com.extendedcontrols).

Comment: What is the point of the brightness toggle? When I turn it off, the screen is barely readable

Comment: If it's pretty dark in the room it's plenty bright enough.

Comment: I work third shift (I'm working right now) so I always have the brightness all the way down. I use the toggle in the rare instances when I'm out in the sun and bump it up to half brightness.

Comment: @casebash depends on your phone's screen type, with the Super AMOLED on my Samsung Galaxy, I've only needed to turn the screen brightness on once in the last month in very bright sunlight, and as we're getting into the gloomy English winter I can't see me needing it again until next year!

Comment: @Casebash The phone should auto-adjust the brightness based on ambient light if you allow it via the brightness toggle. It's not always perfect right away, but I find the few times it is too dim and takes a few seconds to correct is worth the extra battery life it gives.